# Improve CASE WHEN Performance

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to calculate customer retention week over week. My sales_orders table has columns order_date, and customer_name. Basically I want to check if a customer in this week also had an order the previous week. To do this, I have used CASE WHEN and subquery as follows (I have extracted order_week in a cte I've called weekly_customers and gotten distinct customer names within each week):

```
SELECT wc.order_week, 
       wc.customer,
       CASE
           WHEN wc.customer IN (
               SELECT sq.customer 
               FROM weekly_customers sq 
               WHERE sq.order_week = (wc.order_week - 1))
               THEN 'YES'
           ELSE 'NO'
           END  AS present_in_previous_week
from  weekly_customers wc
```

The query returns the correct data. My issue, the table is really huge with about 15000 distinct weekly values. This obviously leads to very long execution time. Is there a way I can improve this loop or even an alternative to the loop altogether?

Comment: You could try a left join instead.

Comment: Have a look at analytical functions such as LAG. It's difficult to be more specific than that without ddl and sample data that illustrates the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
wc.order_week, 
wc.customer,
CASE WHEN wcb.customer IS NOT NULL THEN "YES" ELSE "NO" END AS present_in_previous_week
FROM  weekly_customers AS wca
LEFT JOIN
weekly_customers AS wcb
ON
wca.customer = wcb.customer
AND wca.order_week - 1 = wcb.order_week
```

This joins all of the customer data onto the customer data from a week ago. If there is a record for a week ago then wcb.customer will not be null, and we can set the flag to "YES". Otherwise, we set the flag to "NO".